# WPF. ListBox. How to limit maximum of selected items to 2?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, listbox

I need to limit the number of selected items in a ListBox to 2. How to do this? Is it possible to avoid the usage of events and do this in XAML?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no built-in way to do this as far as I'm aware, so you're going to have to write some code.

You could set your ListBox as multi-select by setting `SelectionMode` to `Multiple` or `Extended` (See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.selectionmode.aspx) for the difference) and attach onto the `SelectionChanged` event. When the event is raised, modify the selection how you see fit (how you do it would depend on how you wanted it to work... if they select a third one, does it get removed right away? or does the first one get removed - effectively FIFO or LIFO removal).

**Edit:**

My bad, I had linked to the wrong article.

Comment: N.B.: In WPF, the SelectionMode enumeration [is different.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.selectionmode.aspx)

Comment: how exactly programatically unselect selected item when the event is raised?

Answer (score 2):

I made a behavior of this where I can bind the number of elements I want to have selected to a dependencyproperty.

It's used like this, attached to a `ListView`

```
<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <behaviors:LimitSelectionBehavior Limit="2" />
</i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

And here is the Behavior class. The `Remove` could be modified to unselect down to the `Limit`, now it just unselects all newly added.

```
public class LimitSelectionBehavior : Behavior<ListView>
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LimitProperty;

    static LimitSelectionBehavior()
    {
        LimitProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Limit", typeof(int), typeof(LimitSelectionBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(default(int)));
    }

    public int Limit
    {
        get { return (int) GetValue(LimitProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LimitProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged += OnSelectionChanged;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged -= OnSelectionChanged;
    }

    private void OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (AssociatedObject.SelectedItems.Count <= Limit)
            return;

        foreach (var added in e.AddedItems)
        {
            AssociatedObject.SelectedItems.Remove(added);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following is an example of how to restrict selection to two items only

For the ListView defined in the following XAML

```
  <ListView x:Name="MyListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ParentSection.MyListItems}" BorderThickness="0"
                SelectionMode="Multiple" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
                mvvm:FrameworkElementBehaviors.IgnoreMouseWheel="True" 
                SelectionChanged="MyListView_SelectionChanged">
    <ListView.View>
    <!--Your list view content here -->
    </ListView.View>
  </ListView>
```

The event would be something like following

```
    public void MyListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.MyListView.SelectedItems.Count > 2)
        {
            this.MyListView.SelectedItems.RemoveAt(0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the example! I would select it as my solution if i would be the OP.