# ListBox: How to deselect/unselect item selected once the maximum limit has been met?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

I am using manual limit of ListBox selected items to 5.

I tried different approaches including some solution applied in some other related issue but still can't make it.

I already tried: **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6050886/wpf-listbox-how-to-limit-maximum-of-selected-items-to-2)** but I cannot follow using "...attach onto the SelectionChanged event". I mean how to do that?

**[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/947285/deselection-on-a-wpf-listbox-with-extended-selection-mode)** :but it clears all the selected items leaving no selected items.

and even setting the .SelectedIndex to -1 or null and the same thing happened. It deselected every selected items.

etc...

**All I want to do is just to deselect(hope this make sense) the last selected item once the limitation is met.**

Or worst solution : Can I disable my ListBox but still displaying the selected items(meaning still highlighted)?

I tried most if in the **SelectionChanged** and some on **Mouse_Down** Event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you follow the answer you linked to then you arrive at something like this:

XAML

```xml
<ListBox x:Name="myListBox" SelectionChanged="myListBox_SelectionChanged" SelectionMode="Multiple">
...
</ListBox>
```

Code behind

```
void myListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // remove items from the end until at most 5 items are in the list
    while (myListBox.SelectedItems.Count > 5)
    {
        myListBox.SelectedItems.RemoveAt(SelectedItems.Count - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: it works! thank you! "if" condition is fine instead of "while". my ListBox is bound to a collection though.

Answer (score 1):

In WPF you could disable all unselected items when the maximum is reached:

```xml
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding SelectedItems.Count, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}}" Value="5"/>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

*(You might want to override the input bindings though as `Ctrl+A` will still select everything)*

Comment: thank you once again. really help me in some other way but in my case right now I want to do it behind the code because maybe later I will add some logic on how to set limitation dynamically. I honestly like your approach (Instead of focusing on the number of selected items, you focus on the remaining unselected items) but again, I want to do it over some useful Events and code